# 12.04 desktop sharing Black Screen

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I know there has to be a simple excuse for this I have however been unable to find it I have used Ubuntu for quite some time and until 12.04 any time I needed VNC access to a Ubuntu Desktop I simply enabled desktop sharing and I could get to from anywhere. In 12.04 and newer I have been unable to make this work all I get is a black screen. I have tried multiple clients on Ubuntu, Slackware, Windows, and Android with no luck.

Thanks
Wayne

Comment: I have this issue too. None of the solutions here (at the time of this comment) fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup copy of your hosts file

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.vncfix
```

Open your hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

comment out with a hash (or remove) the IPv6 sections

```
#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

save, exit and reconnect your VNC session.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue of seeing a blank screen after logging into Ubuntu 12.04 desktop using Remmina.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Desktop Sharing configuration window and untick **You must confirm each access to this machine**. If this option is enabled, you must confirm that you accept the connection by pressing a button on the actual machine that you want to access. Until this happens, your remote screen will stay black.

Hope this solves your problem.